# How to separate longitude and latitude from OpenLayers coordinates

Tags: javascript, position, coordinates, extract, openlayers

The openLayers mousePosition returns the coordinates x,y of the cursor position.

```
var mousePosition = new ol.control.MousePosition({
        undefinedHTML: '&nbsp;',
        projection: 'EPSG:4326',
        coordinateFormat: function(coordinate) {
                        return ol.coordinate.format(coordinate, '{x}, {y}', 6);
                      },
        className: 'ol-mouse-position',
        target: document.getElementById('myposition'),    
      });
```

What is the easiest way to extract longitude and latitude and use both values for displaying in a form? What is the structure of coordinateFormat?

Answer (score 2):

The coordinate value is a plain JavaScript Array. You can access the values like so:

```js
var x = coordinate[0];
var y = coordinate[1];
```

See the [API docs on Coordinate](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_coordinate.html#~Coordinate) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks! I was thinking too complicated. Sorry. 
I am using it here
`map.on('click', function(evt){var lonlat=(ol.proj.transform(evt.coordinate,  'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326'));
coordlon=(lonlat['0']).toFixed(6);
coordlat=(lonlat['1']).toFixed(6); document.getElementById('lat').innerHTML=coordlat; document.getElementById('lon').innerHTML=coordlon;});`
Again, thanks for the hint!